# eslint "no-labels" warning w javascript in reactjs

Tags: eslint

I'm using a label for convenience, to break a simple `if` statement. Yet react is complaining about "no-labels" and finding out what that means has sent me on a wild goose chase.

```
Unexpected labeled statement         no-labels
Unexpected label in break statement  no-labels
```

**Question**

I realize labels aren't the most popular, is that why they are frowned upon? Is the only way to get around this to `// eslint-disable-next-line` or use a collection of scopes/functions instead?

**Code Example**

```
opt:
if([something true]) {
    ...
    while([some value]) {
        ...
        break opt;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During research for this question I decided to go with `// eslint-disable-next-line`

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
opt:
...
```

While this warning is in the spirit of "clean, understandable code" it's clear to me that the benefits of where & how I'm using this label supersedes the warning.